# Prohibited Parcel Items from the UK to Ukraine

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, ukraine, mail, shipping

I'm putting together a parcel for someone I know in Ukraine and I'm concerned that the contents will will be destroyed by customs if I ship these items.

I want to send:

- Chocolate
- Jelly Sweets
- Shower Gel
- Two packs of hair dye:

  - L'Oreal Paris Casting Creme Gloss 360
  - L'Oreal Paris Casting Creme Gloss 565

The thing that concerns me the most is the hair dye. Is that allowed to be sent to Ukraine?

I could not find anything online to say whether these hair dyes are prohibited to enter/ be sent to Ukraine? Please can someone advise? They're just cosmetic products so I don't see why not but I'd like to know in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not related to travel.

Comment: Sorry, Boris, but sending things by post isn't travelling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very limited list of items *generally* prohibited for importing (like drugs, alcohol, and firearms). You may **check the components** of items you're planning to send to see if there's any prohibited component within.

My personal opinion is that with the items you listed, you're all fine, just care about any **alcohol component**.

Here's [the exact list of items prohibited for importing](http://sfs.gov.ua/baneryi/mitne-oformlennya/subektam-zed/zaboroni-ta-obmejennya-pri-peremischenni/), but it is in Ukrainian, and each item refers to its particular article in the *Ukrainian Classification of Goods for Foreign Economic Activity* (Українська класифікація товарів зовнішньоекономічної діяльності, УКТ ЗЕД).

In any case, make sure you **declare** all the contents of your shipment on your paperwork. If you believe that your goods may need permission to clear customs, be sure to [contact Ukraine customs](http://sfs.gov.ua/en/) before booking your shipment or ask your Ukrainian friend call the Contact Center Department of the State Fiscal Service of Ukraine - Tel. +380 (800) 501-007

The rest depends on your carrier's rules. Here are some to consider:

- [**UkrPoshta**](https://ukrposhta.ua/en/dovidka/predmeti-shho-zaboroneni-do-peresilannya/) (Ukrainian Post);
- [**Royal Mail**](https://www.royalmail.com/ukraine);
- [**DHL** Express Import Guidelines](https://www.dhl.com.ua/en/country_profile/import_guidelines_express.html): Ukraine;
- [**FedEx**](https://crossborder.fedex.com/us/assets/prohibited-restricted/ukraine/index.shtml) Ukraine Prohibited and Restricted Items;
- [**USPS** Country Conditions for Mailing](https://pe.usps.com/IMM_Archive/HTML/IMM_Archive_20060108/imm/immicl/immicltz_015.html) - Ukraine;

---

Alternatively, I have a very positive experience with Internet shops who would buy cosmetics in Europe, deliver it to Ukraine, and send it locally to your door. Their fees would be higher than normal parcel delivery (say, +20-25% of the item's price), but it frees you up from any paperwork, and there's no risk of damaged/stolen item because you pay when receiving.

Comment: Please could you let me know the names of these internet stores?